# What conditions are required to say $\lim \int |f_n - g_n| =0$, where $f_n, g_n$ : PDFs of random variable.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Is there hint/reference, that the conditions to be met in order to say

$$\lim \int |f_n - g_n| =0$$

$f_n, g_n$ : PDFs of random variables, $X_n, Y_n$.

Is it sufficient to show that $X_n \to c$, $Y_n \to c$, both almost surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same density function i.e. $(f_n=g_n)$ then $\int|f_n-g_n|=0$ for all
$n$.  Your condition that the random variables have the same constant limit is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, $X_n=X/n$ and  $Y=-X/n$ then $\int |f_n-g_n|$ doe not tend to $0$.

Comment: This isn't quite true. If $X$ is a *zero-mean* uniform distribution, then $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same pdf, hence $f_n - g_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I meant uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.